# Unsupported resolution in Mirror's Edge

Tags: technical-issues, mirrors-edge

I just installed the game,  **Mirror's Edge**  but unfortunately my LCD monitor isn't supporting its default resolution.

My LCD monitor's resolution is 1024x768 60Hz.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Do you even get one or does the game just crash?

Comment: Its not the error, its just the resolution problem. Game is working  because I can hear the sound but not getting video. My monitor says "out the frequency".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found some discussions about this issue, like [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20170602225932/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2578911)

From these guys, you're right about it being a resolution issue. You can manually overwrite it by **editing the Documents/EA Games/Mirrors Edge/TdGame/config/TdEngine.ini file and change the ResX and ResY values**.

Try to put your monitor values there, apparently that worked for him.

Comment: Yes, It worked.

Comment: Good to hear, enjoy the game ;)